# How to verify generated reports on Tableau UI using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, tableau-api

How can I click/assert or verify elements on a canvas withing a web browser UI when using Selenium?
I want to assert for pre-defined graphs/reports in web application.

Comment: I'm not sure there is question here. Can't you just assert for a graph like you can any other element on a page?

Comment: No you can't, the tableau graphs are on a canvas. There is only the canvas element and not individually.

Comment: And each graph is it's own canvas element? Or there is only 1 canvas element?

Comment: There is just one canvas element.